# Can I bring fast food in my checked luggage on a flight to the USA?

Tags: air-travel, usa, luggage, canada

I'm flying from Canada to the United States. I'd like to bring my friend a couple burgers and fries from a local chain that doesn't exist where he lives in the United States. Is this allowed?

Comment: even if it were allowed, would the food really be in a state that's appealing to eat after you get home?

Comment: [Not very likely.](http://www.foxnews.com/leisure/2013/04/25/14-year-old-mcdonald-hamburger-looks-almost-new/)

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely not edit: because it is not commercially packaged.

https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/82/~/travelers-bringing-food-into-the-u.s.-for-personal-use

> Food products from Canada, including pet food and fresh (frozen or chilled), cooked, canned or otherwise processed products containing beef, veal, bison, and cervid (e.g. deer, elk, moose, caribou etc.) are now permitted from Canada in passenger baggage. Products containing sheep, lamb, or goat will not be allowed entry. **Food products should be commercially packaged and sealed with ingredients listed in English.**

Comment: and a paper wrapped burger will almost certainly not have its ingredients listed either...

Comment: @chx If the fast-food chain exists within the airport (after security).. Is this therefore still NOT valid to come on? I am pretty sure they have chains such as Burger King, Mcdonalds after security..

Comment: @Phorce That's sort of irrelevant since you check your luggage before you clear security (at least in every airport I've ever travelled from). Barring any rules specific to the airline you're flying with, carrying on (fast) food bought within the airport is allowed.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It's irrelevant if the fast food chain that the o/p is asking about is within the airport itself. That being said, they have not expressed this so... You're right :)